# Java's String.getByte() vs C#

Tags: c#, java, encoding, windows-phone

I have some code in Java that use

```
String.getBytes()
```

(without encoding parameters) on some generated string to obtain `byte[]` which I later use as a key for AES encryption.

Then I take the encoded message and under C# (WP7/WP8 environment) I need to decode it.
I can easily generate the string that I've used in Java application, however I need to convert this to `byte[]` in such way that it will generate exactly the same byte array as in Java.

Question 1:
Can I do this without altering Java code?

Question 2:
If not, how should I implement both version so they will always return the same `byte[]` no matter what?

Comment: As I am no Java-Dev: What encoding does a `String` in Java have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you should specify an encoding in the Java code. Currently, your code will produce different outputs on different systems as it uses the platform-default encoding (e.g. Windows-1252 or UTF-8).

I would encourage you to use UTF-8 in both cases:

```
// Java 7 onwards
byte[] bytes = text.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

// Java pre-7
byte[] bytes = text.getBytes("UTF-8");

// .NET
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
```

Using UTF-8 allows for *all* valid Unicode strings to be encoded into bytes. You could consider using UTF-16, but then you need to make sure you specify the same endianness in each case. That does have the benefit of having exactly two bytes per `char` regardless of content though (as a `char` is a UTF-16 code unit in both Java and .NET).

Comment: So basically, if I use UTF-8 I will always end up with the same byte arrays on both platforms? Event if there are some two-bytes-characters they will end up with the same byte order on both platforms?

Comment: @Dzior: Yes, exactly.